# No me encuentra una clase POO en php

Tags: php, mysql, poo

estoy haciendo una conexion a una BBDD A traves de POO y me esta arrojando un error sobre que no me encuentra la clase "Conexion", pero yo la tengo agregada como herencia dentro de la clase "DevuelveProductos".

Tengo 3 archivos php.

1) El que hace la conexion con la BBDD llamado (Conexion_BBDD_con_clases_poo.php):

```
require "datosconexion.php";
 class Conexion{
    protected $conexion_db;

        function __construct(){

            $this->conexion_db=new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USUARIO, DB_CONTRA, DB_NOMBRE);

                if ($this->conexion_db->connect_errno){
                    echo "No se pudo establecer conexion con la base de datos" . $this->conexion_db->connect_error;
                return;
    }
    $this->conexion_db->set_charset(DB_CHARSET);
}
```

}

El contenedor de la informacion de la BBDD llamado (datosconexion.php):

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USUARIO', 'root');
    define('DB_CONTRA', '');
        define('DB_NOMBRE', 'pruebas');
            define('DB_CHARSET', 'uft8');
```

3) El que devuelve los productos de la consulta (devuelve_productos.php)

```
require "datosconexion.php";
                    //heredando todo de la clase Conexion
class DevuelveProductos extends Conexion{                               /* Clases Conexion ---> DevuelveProductos */

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); //Llamando constructor de la clase padre(CONEXION), CONECTANDO CON LA BASE DE DATOS
}
public function get_productos(){
    $resultado=$this->conexion_db->query('SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS'); //CONSULTA SQL
    $productos=$resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); //ALMACENANDO RSULTADOS DE LA CONSULTA SQL
    return $productos; //NUNCA OLVIDAR EL RETURN, NOS ARROJA EL ARRAY
}
```

}

y el index :

```
<?php 
//Incluyendo los archivos antes hechos
require "devuelve_productos.php";
//creando instancias de la clase devuelve_productos, y se crea para que se ejecute dentro de la clase DevuelveProductos()
$productos=new DevuelveProductos();
//Fin instancia
$array_productos=$productos->get_productos();
```

?>
 
 
 
    
    
    Html

```
foreach ($array_productos as $elementofila){
    echo "<table><tr><td>";
    echo $elementofila["CÓDIGOARTÍCULO"] . "</td><td>";
    echo $elementofila["NOMBREARTÍCULO"] . "</td><td>";
    echo $elementofila["SECCIÓN"] . "</td><td>";
    echo $elementofila["PRECIO"] . "</td><td>";
    echo $elementofila["FECHA"] . "</td><td>";
    echo $elementofila["IMPORTADO"] . "</td><td>";
    echo $elementofila["PAÍSDEORIGEN"] . "</td><td></tr></table>";

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";

}   

 ?>
```

y me esta apareciendo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el error lo esta dando en la linea 4 que es :

> class DevuelveProductos extends Conexion{

del archivo devuelve_productos.php

Comment: Creo mas no estoy seguro es porque no estas enlazando tu archivo `Conexion_BBDD_con_clases_poo.php`, en `devuelve_productos.php`, estas llamando es a tu archivo que contiene los datos de la `BBDD` mas no el que realiza la conexion como tal

Comment: tal vez te falte el `require_once` del file.php donde definís la clase

Comment: Cuando incluyo Conex... en devuel... (Include "Conexion_BBDD_con_clases_poo.php") me aparece la pag index llena de errores sobre que las constantes "DB_USUARIO..." Ya estan definidas y que el index esta sin definir en todo momento.

Comment: por eso el `_once`

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado, tenia 2 errores:

**Primer error :**

No estaba incluyendo `Conexion_BBDD_con_clases_poo.php` en `devuelve_productos.php` Por lo tanto me arrojaba el error de que no se encontraba la clase "Conexion"

**Segundo error :**
Las columnas de la base de datos se encontraba así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me lanzaba el error **[INDEX ERROR...]**

La solucion fue quitar los acentos existentes en las columnas, Pasando de

> "C**Ó**DIGOART**Í**CULO -> CODIGOARTICULO"

Al quitar los acentos de cada columna se me resolvió el problema completamente.